# ChromeOS init problems

Tags: bash, init, upstart, google-chrome-os

Currently having issues when attempting to run a MAC changing script on startup.

Currently running ChromeOS which is using upstart as it's init system however I've attempted multiple different ways to make the script run at boot with no luck.

Running the script alone via sudo sh updatemac.sh has it working correctly, code here:

```
#!/bin/bash

NEW_MAC=`echo -n 00; hexdump -n 5 -v -e '/1 ":%02X"' /dev/urandom;`

ifconfig wlan0 down
ifconfig wlan0 hw ether $NEW_MAC
ifconfig wlan0 up
```

I've attempted to create a startup job a few different ways.

First way was placing updatemac.conf in /etc/init with the code:

```
start on star-user-session
task

script 

NEW_MAC=`echo -n 00; hexdump -n 5 -v -e '/1 ":%02X"' /dev/urandom;`

ifconfig wlan0 down
ifconfig wlan0 hw ether $NEW_MAC
ifconfig wlan0 up

end script
```

However that didn't work. I also tried replacing the script / end script section with both

```
exec /home/user/chronos/Downloads/updatemac.sh
```

And

```
exec sh /home/user/chronos/Downloads/updatemac.sh
```

Neither of which worked.

The other way I tried was adding the script directly to /etc/init.d/updatemac.sh

However that also failed for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it, seems it needed

```
start on started system-services
```

In the .conf for /etc/init instead of

```
start on star-user-session
```

Also removed "task" from the script.